# Wordpress menu_nav active class to <a href

Tags: wordpress, function, menu

how can i add active class to menu

I have:

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="">A</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="">B</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-26 active "><a href="">C</a></li>
```

And i need:

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="" class="active">A</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="">B</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-26 active "><a href="">C</a></li>
```

I know how to add the active class to "li" element with functions.
But how can i add it to a href?

Comment: Why do you need it on the anchor?

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to use javascript.

You can do it this way:

```
$('.menu-item').hasClass('.current-menu-item').children('a').addClass('active');
```